# Opencart Module Adjustment

Tags: module, opencart

Please, I need help adjusting the "Order Invoice" module to fit in firmly on the same row with the Featured Products module on this site am working on (cedamart.com). It pushes down the Featured Products module. I want to ask if the adjustment has to be done in the module's code or in the theme's stylesheet? Your kind help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully done this lower on the page with the Bestseller box on the left and the laptops box in the center.  Look at how they are styled:

Bestseller:

```
<div class="box boss_column_filter five columns alpha boss_bestseller" id="box_column_filter_0">
  <div class="box-heading">Best Seller</div>
  <div class="box-content">
```

Laptops:

```
<div class="box boss_homecategory_nonetab fourteen columns " id="box_homecategory_nonetab_0">
    <div class="box-heading"><span>Laptops</span></div>
```

Just replicate this styling.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I've resolved it but by adding a float:left styling to the module's code. Thank you.